LexikJWTAuthentication Authenticator does not support the request
I'm using symfony 7.1, api-platform and lexikJWTAuthentication.
I use this endpoint to log in : http://localhost:8000/api/login
I'm trying to understand whats happening here, i see this in my logs:

[2024-10-20T22:45:57.614291+00:00] request.INFO: Matched route "login". {"route":"login","route_parameters":{"_route":"login"},"request_uri":"http://localhost:8000/api/login","method":"POST"} []
[2024-10-20T22:45:57.634711+00:00] security.DEBUG: Checking for authenticator support. {"firewall_name":"main","authenticators":2} []
[2024-10-20T22:45:57.634753+00:00] security.DEBUG: Checking support on authenticator. {"firewall_name":"main","authenticator":"Lexik\Bundle\JWTAuthenticationBundle\Security\Authenticator\JWTAuthenticator"} []
[2024-10-20T22:45:57.634779+00:00] security.DEBUG: Authenticator does not support the request. {"firewall_name":"main","authenticator":"Lexik\Bundle\JWTAuthenticationBundle\Security\Authenticator\JWTAuthenticator"} []
[2024-10-20T22:45:57.634796+00:00] security.DEBUG: Checking support on authenticator. {"firewall_name":"main","authenticator":"Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Authenticator\JsonLoginAuthenticator"} []

That means, the auth is being accepted by JsonLoginAuthenticator not by JWTAuthenticator
Here is my services.yml
security:
   # https://symfony.com/doc/current/security.html#registering-the-user-hashing-passwords
   password_hashers:
       Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\PasswordAuthenticatedUserInterface: 'auto'
   # https://symfony.com/doc/current/security.html#loading-the-user-the-user-provider
   providers:
       # used to reload user from session & other features (e.g. switch_user)
       app_user_provider:
           entity:
               class: App\Entity\User
               property: email
   firewalls:
       dev:
           pattern: ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
           security: false
       main:
           stateless: true
           provider: app_user_provider
           json_login:
               check_path: login
               username_path: email
               password_path: password
               success_handler: lexik_jwt_authentication.handler.authentication_success
               failure_handler: lexik_jwt_authentication.handler.authentication_failure
           jwt: 
       api:
           pattern:   ^/api
           stateless: true 
           jwt: ~ 

   access_control:
       - { path: ^/api/login, roles: PUBLIC_ACCESS }
       - { path: ^/api/register, roles: PUBLIC_ACCESS }
       - { path: ^/api$, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY }

when@test:
   security:
       password_hashers:
           # By default, password hashers are resource intensive and take time. This is
           # important to generate secure password hashes. In tests however, secure hashes
           # are not important, waste resources and increase test times. The following
           # reduces the work factor to the lowest possible values.
           Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\PasswordAuthenticatedUserInterface:
               algorithm: auto
               cost: 4 # Lowest possible value for bcrypt
               time_cost: 3 # Lowest possible value for argon
               memory_cost: 10 # Lowest possible value for argon


my routes.yml
controllers:
    resource:
        path: ../src/Controller/
        namespace: App\Controller
    type: attribute

login:
    path: /api/login
    methods: ['POST']

And my lexik_jwt_authentication.yaml
lexik_jwt_authentication:
    secret_key: '%env(resolve:JWT_SECRET_KEY)%'
    public_key: '%env(resolve:JWT_PUBLIC_KEY)%'
    pass_phrase: '%env(JWT_PASSPHRASE)%'
    token_ttl: 3600
    api_platform:
        check_path: /api/login
        username_path: email
        password_path: security.credentials.password


I just followed the documentation
https://symfony.com/bundles/LexikJWTAuthenticationBundle/current/index.html
My token is being generated, but not generated by JWT authenticator, I just want make an event subscriber to JWT authentication

I believe your api firewall should be declared before your main firewall.
The first firewall that matches is used by Symfony, and since you have no pattern on main, it is used to handle everything, even for the ^/api paths.
